# Displaying PDF files in shiny app doesn't work for all OS and browsers

Tags: r, windows, pdf, browser, shiny

I have developed a shiny app which basically just displays pdf files. This works like a charm on my Mac within Safari browser, but for example not within OSX Firefox. 
On Windows it doesn't seem to work at all for IE (or Edge) or Firefox.
One colleague tested it on Linux and it works in Firefox and Chrome.

Here it the link to the shiny app https://butterlab.imb-mainz.de/EvoAnnotate/

Does anyone has a suggestion what I could do? I would prefer to display the PDFs compared to PNG for example, because the file size is much bigger for PNG and the resolution is always limited.

As a reproducible example, here is some code. It expects to have a file called `test.pdf` in the working directory.

```
ui <- shiny::fluidPage(
  imageOutput("myImage")
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$myImage <- renderImage({
    list(src = 'test.pdf',
         contentType = 'application/pdf',
         width = 960,
         height = 680,
         alt = 'test.pdf')
  },
  deleteFile=FALSE)
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**EDIT:**

I created now for all PDF files a png version and provide a switch for the user, in case the PDF isn't displayed. Not the best solution, but Maybe someone can suggest something more interactive? Maybe using javascript to check if the file is displayed?

Comment: Is the pdf file you are trying to display stored locally or in a web server ?

Comment: It is the path of the file within the web server. It is displayed within some browsers, but not in all.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't work because a PDF isn't strictly an image per se, and `renderImage` attempts to display the object within an `<img>` tag on the webpage. My thoughts are that the browsers that do show the PDF are an anomaly, not the standard. More broadly searching how to display a PDF on a webpage reveals that one way is to use an `<iframe>`. ([see here](https://pdfobject.com/static.html))

So one way to achieve this could be to alternate between having an `<img>` tag and an `<iframe>`

```
output$myImage <- renderUI({
  if (input$toggle == "PDF") {
    tags$iframe(style = 'height: 680px; width: 960px;',
                src = 'test.pdf')
  } else if (input$toggle == "PNG") {
    tags$img(style = 'height: 680px; width: 960px;',
             src = 'test.pdf')
  }
})
```

Comment: I have in mind, that `iframe`s are something oldschool back in 2000 or so. Do you know if this is generally supported throughout the web? I have no experiences on this. I just realised on my mac, within the `img` tag and the content type properly set, everything works.

Comment: Yes, `iframe`s are widely used across the web anytime people show a web page within another webpage (e.g. on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/), a popular tool with web developers)
[The supported formats for `img` aren't specified](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#Supported_image_formats) but don't typically include PDF. MacOS supports it natively but others need stuff like Adobe Acrobat